# Cloud Run: container terminated on signal 9

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-run, moviepy

I have a Cloud Run function that used to work well for ~6 months.

It runs some video aggregations and manipulations in Python using `moviepy`, so it's mostly CPU.

Suddendly it started to fail with some I/O error from `moviepy`. Inspecting the logs I see it always fails right after `container terminated on signal 9` warning.

As far as I understand this is google scaling down deployments.

My questions are:

- why it suddendly started to fail? It is the first time I see this signal 9 warnings
- is there a way to workaround them? (e.g. reserving a single container without scaling up and down)?

[image]

Comment: `container terminated on signal 9` is thrown when memory exceeds, try increasing memory. Meanwhile, can you share error logs?

Comment: Do you have more log trace?